# JUnit Suite Class Re-Run failed tests

Tags: java, junit, suite

I have a JUnit suite that id like to rerun failed tests. At the moment when the suite executes some scripts are failing due to environment issues. These issues are outside of my control so I need to implement some functionality that allows me to execute the failed scripts. Im not sure how to implement such a solution.

An example of my suite class is as follows.

```
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

import com.test.junit.testSuite.AbstractTestSuite;
import com.test.tests.testClasses.TestScript1;
import com.test.tests.testClasses.TestScript3;
import com.test.tests.testClasses.TestScript2ShouldFail;

@Suite.SuiteClasses({ TestScript1.class,TestScript2ShouldFail.class,
    TestScript3.class})

public class FullTestSuite extends AbstractTestSuite
{

}
```

Comment: These 'scripts' are the JUnit test classes? What do you do in you program if these environment issues fail? You must ensure that the environment is set up correctly before testing.